# Instagram like-list is incomplete

Tags: list, instagram, social-media-like

I've made a little photosite, where users can watch and like images.
If an image has already been liked, then it should be unliked - and vice versa.

The problem is that Instagram returns an incomplete list of people, liking the image - and then, I can't tell if a user already likes an image.

Try looking at this JSON:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/saycheasy/media/recent?client_id=ef55f2eb8029413bbd01bdf9ce2f0ff1

At the first image, for instance, it currently says that 11 people likes this image - but only 4 are shown. I'm aware that there's an upper limit, but not as low as 4. A similar question on stackoverflow refers to a 120-limit...

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question still stands - but I found a clumsy work-around method. Instagram returns all of the ID's of the users, liking an image when running this: 

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/753028255421401504_249583681/likes?client_id=ef55f2eb8029413bbd01bdf9ce2f0ff1

I then made AJAX-calls for every image, substituting the ID with the individual photo ID's. It means that when loading 20 photos, the server has to make a lot of querys - but I found no other way.

Comment: I think the link does not work. it returns {
  "meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
    "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."
  }
}

Comment: Since this is an old thread, I'm not sure if the client_id is active anymore. If not, you would probably at least need to supply your own client_id in order to get it working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link does not work anymore and the issue can't be reproduced (JSON not available)

Comment: Be my guest - but did you use your own client_id?

Comment: I don't have one. You should provide the JSON you are asking about, or it is not possible to help you.

Comment: Is it that JSON you get https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/  open Response dropdown in second GET example. I don't see any list of users in this example

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Closing the question...